# MobX observe JavaScript object / reference

Tags: mobx

I'm trying to merge the apollo store with mobx using the following library.
https://github.com/sonaye/mobx-apollo

It just tries to wrap the apollo store with an observable mobx layer like so:

```
import { action, observable } from 'mobx';

const graphql = config => {
  const { client, onError, onFetch, ...opts } = config;
  const query = client.watchQuery(opts);
  const observableQuery = observable(query.currentResult());

  query.subscribe({
    next: action(value => {
      observableQuery.error = undefined;
      observableQuery.loading = value.loading;
      observableQuery.data = value.data;
      if (onFetch) onFetch(value.data);
    }),
    error: action(error => {
      observableQuery.error = error;
      observableQuery.loading = false;
      observableQuery.data = undefined;
      if (onError) onError(error);
    })
  });

  observableQuery.ref = query;
  return observableQuery;
};

export default graphql;
```

---

The problem is the library gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot define property __mobxDidRunLazyInitializers, object is not extensible
```

It seems as though `const observableQuery = observable(query.currentResult())` is causing the issue. `query.currentResult()` returns a javascript object which just looks like the following, and will be updated once the data is fetched (although we never get that far)

```
{
    "data": {},
    "loading": true,
    "networkStatus": 1,
    "partial": true
}
```

---

Is there a way to make mobx correctly observe an object or a reference to an object?

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/xv1wxl14xo

Comment: You need write `graphql` as a class in this case. The decorator need to access the observable variables. The variables defined inside the function are hidden from outside, so it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the same issue using MobX 4.0 with a simple @observable.deep.

Reverting back to 3.x solves the problem. This is confirmed. Working for me in mobx 3.6.2 / mobx-react 4.4.3

Comment: Yes, seems like the following might be working...
    `"mobx": "3.6.2",
    "mobx-react": "4.4.0",`

Comment: Will look further into it!

Comment: Confirmed. Working for me in mobx 3.6.2 / mobx-react 4.4.3.

Comment: Ok this has now been fixed with mobx 4.0.2